# Securing ASP.Net Website?

Tags: asp.net, security

How to secure ASP.Net Website ( Commercial Application ) using SQL 2008 ? We are working on securing both on Front ( Web App) and Back End ( Protecting from SQL Injection ) ..!
Other than Secured Protocol .. from programming end , what are the security measurements we would consider ?

Comment: You should consider using Linux.

Comment: @Rook: How exactly using Linux going to improve his programming practices?

Comment: @R0MANARMY the impact of common venerabilities such as SQL Injection is lessoned under a solid platform.  Security measures such as SELinux  and/or apparomor are apart of the linux mainline and are enabled by default on most distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is good reference on MSDN:

[How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998271.aspx)

[Microsoft Patterns & Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650055.aspx) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The [Developer Highway Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/security/aa473878.aspx) is an excellent checklist which I would recommend you reading.

Comment: I did that, I believe .. from Architect point of view - Microsoft Design Patterns & Securities play an Important role ..!

Answer (score 0):

Using https is not a silver bullet for creating secure applications!

I recommend getting a copy of [Beginning ASP.NET Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470743654). It's got chapters on everything you'll need for security, including Cross-Site Scripting, input validation, SQL injection, cryptography and AJAX.

Comment: When you say Https , i already mentioned about Secured Protocols ..! I am talking from basic development end .. !